# Docker redsocks proxy behind HTTP proxy with no internet DNS

Tags: proxy, docker, iptables

## Network Environment

- No internet DNS available
- Corporate squid proxy allowing HTTP and HTTPS traffic on port 3128

## Docker Environment

Docker is running on an Ubuntu 15.04 guest inside VirtualBox on OS X.

A container `docker-forgetproxy` (https://github.com/k-labs/docker-forgetproxy) which is running `redsocks` on top of the host's network infrastructure, run with:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --net=host --privileged \
                 -e http_proxy=$http_proxy \
                 -e https_proxy=$https_proxy \
                 klabs/docker-forgetproxy
```

This modifies the host's iptables rules by issuing the following commands where `$1` is set to `A`:

```
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -i docker0 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -i docker0 -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -i docker0 -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -i docker0 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -i docker0 -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -i docker0 -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80   -i docker0 -j REDIRECT --to 12345 2>/dev/null
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -i docker0 -j REDIRECT --to 12345 2>/dev/null
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53   -i docker0 -j REDIRECT --to 5300
iptables -t nat -$1 PREROUTING -p tcp -i docker0 -j REDIRECT --to 12346
```

and launches `redsocks` is launched with the

```
base {
  log_debug = off;
  log_info = on;
  log = "stderr";
  daemon = off;
  user = redsocks;
  group = redsocks;
  redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
  type = http-relay;
  ip = http://my-proxy;
  port = 3128;
  local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
  local_port = 12345;
}

redsocks {
  type = http-connect;
  ip = http://my-proxy;
  port = 3128;
  local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
  local_port = 12346;
}

dnstc {
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    local_port = 5300;
}
```

## Problem

When I launch a new docker container with `docker run -it --rm ubuntu apt-get update` it seems the container's requests aren't getting rerouted to the `redsocks` container.

Watching the packets on wireshark it appears the DNS resolution for archive.ubuntu.com from the `apt-get` container tries to go to my domain DNS server (which can't perform internet look ups) if I set the DNS server to that of the `docker0` iface it seems it gets captured by the 172.16.0.0/12 iptables rule since today it was 172.17.42.1

Comment: More info over at the [docker-forgetproxy](https://github.com/k-labs/docker-forgetproxy/issues/2)  github page

Answer (score 0):

This applies to a **Ubuntu Xenial** host.

On your host, under Connection Information, get your current DNS addresses; in my case, `172.21.17.212` and `172.21.17.210`.

Under `/etc/default/docker`, add the DNS addresses on `DOCKER_OPTS`:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.21.17.212 --dns 172.21.17.210"
```

Create `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/ubuntu.conf`, with the following:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```